# How to make function to return integer point 2D in C

Tags: c

I have a problem about return integer point 2D. Assume that I have a integer point 2D which represent 2D matrix. And I want to transpose the matrix. I already run successfully if I using normal way (return int**) but the problem is that cannot delete memory when malloc. So I want to convert this function to return void using reference  function as void transposeMatrix(....)//It will return transposed of matrix G

```
int** transposeMatrix(int** G,int  nRowSize,int nColumnSize)
{
    int **GT=NULL;
    int nRowIndex,nColumnIndex;
    GT= (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * nRowSize);
    memset(GT, 0, sizeof(int*) * nRowSize);
    for (nRowIndex = 0; nRowIndex < nRowSize; nRowIndex++)
        {
        GT[nRowIndex] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nColumnSize);
        for (nColumnIndex = 0; nColumnIndex < nColumnSize; nColumnIndex++)
            {
                       GT[nRowIndex][nColumnIndex]=G[nColumnIndex][nRowIndex];
            }
        }
     return  GT;
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: It can be  used by C++. But I think malloc and new is same way. So I tag C++

Comment: Do you want it to return `G`, or take `G` by reference and return void?

Comment: `malloc` and `new` are not the same thing.

Comment: This would be horrible C++ code. If you want to use C++ please tag it **only** as C++ and you’ll get a proper solution.

Comment: @Beta: I want to return transposed of G matrix. So I using temp matrix such as GT and I call it using G_transport=transposeMatrix(G, nRowSize, nColumnSize)

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph: I am very happy if you show one solution to resolve it using C++

Comment: You already do that with the code you have posted. What do you want to delete? (And please don't say "I want to delete malloc", it hurts me.)

Comment: @Beta:Sorry, my comment that means I want to delete memory that is allocated by malloc function. In addition, What is GT in your function, beta? you did identify it?

Comment: So you want to delete the original matrix within your function, and later delete the transposed matrix in the calling code, is that right?

Comment: You must not delete the memory allocate until your calling program is done using the transpose matrix - if you do, you can't use. The result any more. You should write a "delete2D" function that properly undoes the memory allocation when you are done with the transpose - apart from that you are fine.

Comment: @Beta: Because in my function using malloc so the program will allocate memory. If I delete it in this function-it is error because in my function return GT. If I free in outside, it is malloc problem.Is my thinking correct ?

Comment: No, freeing that memory outside the function is not a "malloc problem".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer to `G`:

```
void transposeMatrix(int*** PG,int  nRowSize,int nColumnSize)
}
  ...
  GT[nRowIndex][nColumnIndex]=(*PG)[nColumnIndex][nRowIndex];
  ...
  *GP = GT;
}
```

or pass `G` by reference (I don't remember whether C allows this):

```
void transposeMatrix(int** &G,int  nRowSize,int nColumnSize)
}
  ...
  GT[nRowIndex][nColumnIndex]=G[nColumnIndex][nRowIndex];
  ...
  G = GT;
}
```

Comment: What is GT in your function?I think it must have 4 parameter such as  void transposeMatrix(int** &GT,int** &G,int  nRowSize,int nColumnSize)

Comment: Why would you make a pointer of something that is a pointer already, that doesn't make any sense and is redundant. G is a pointer already. thus leaving it like void 'transposeMatrix(int **PG, int nRowSize, int nColumnSize)' works perfectly fine

Comment: @WhozCraig: The question reads "I want to convert this function to return void", but the OP implies elsewhere (and now states in the comments) that the function should return the transposed matrix. I was taking a guess. And I am aware of the memory leak, I was trying to tackle one question at a time.

Comment: @user2938494: `GT` is the same in my functions as in yours.

Comment: @Montaldo: Yes it makes sense to those who understand pointers, no it is not redundant, no your approach does not work.

Comment: Oh I get the pointer usage, and of that I have no issue. Were I mandated to write a `void fn()` I would likely do similar (unless it is C++, obviously). You're quite correct on the differing requirements stated in the question (void vs not-void).

Comment: @Beta: My question is in your "void transposeMatrix(int** &G,int  nRowSize,int nColumnSize)" you using GT but it did not identify. So your solution is not correct. If you identify that mean you must allocate memory to GT. Memory leak problem

Comment: @user2938494 So, you know what is potentially wrong with someone's answer, but not what is wrong with your own code? I C... "So I want to convert this function to return `void`". This is the way to do that.

Comment: @user2938494: Perhaps you did not notice the ellipses ("...") in my answer. I can solve your memory leak problem, but I'm getting tired of being told that my correct solutions are incorrect.

Comment: @Beta I take back my original comment and will drop it outright. The OP asked for void retval with modified in-out param at the onset, and should stick with it (and +1 to this answer).

Comment: @WhozCraig: I took no offense at your original comment, it was quite correct. And Montaldo was a mere annoyance. But the OP's last comment rubbed me the wrong way, so I think I'll wash my hands of this problem.

Comment: No worries, man. If the OP want's to repurpose a matrix by-address to be its own transposition this is the way to do it. if they want a new one generated and retain the old one then this is only a couple of minor changes away from that as well (literally a return statement in place of a dereferenced assignment). It is the correct answer, and all I can do is up-vote it. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Alright after having some thoughts about your question again, because I very much liked the subject. I kinda I feel I came to a proper solution. The transpose function takes the changes the matrix m such that it points to the proper memory address of the transposed matrix. Thereby it frees the previous matrix m to solve any memory leeks and changing the dimensions for proper use in the caller.

Please comment if there are still parts missing.

I hope this helps. All the best

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int **matrix;

matrix newMatrix(int row, int col)
{
    int idx;
    matrix m = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));
    for (idx = 0; idx < row; ++idx)
    {
        m[idx] = malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    }
    return m;
}

void freeMatrix(matrix m, int row, int col)
{
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < row; ++idx)
    {
        free(m[idx]);
    }
    free(m);
}

void printMatrix(matrix m, int row, int col)
{
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            printf("%d ", m[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int h = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = h;
}

void transpose(matrix *m, int *row, int *col)
{
    int r, c;
    matrix t = newMatrix(*col, *row);

    for (r = 0; r < *row; ++r)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < *col; ++c)
        {
            t[c][r] = (*m)[r][c];
        }
    }
    freeMatrix(*m, *row, *col);
    swap(row, col); 
    (*m) = t;
}

int main()
{
    int row = 2, col = 3;
    matrix m = newMatrix(row, col);

    m[0][0] = 1;
    m[0][1] = 1;
    m[0][2] = 1;
    m[1][0] = 2;
    m[1][1] = 4;
    m[1][2] = 3;

    printMatrix(m, row, col);
    transpose(&m, &row, &col);
    printMatrix(m, row, col);       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you test it? I have checked it and some comments: 1:when you using malloc function, you have to assign  int* or int** beside it. second: freeMatrix did not work. I must delete this function, the result will correct. But when using it. the programming is crashed. I am using visual studio 2010. Thank Montaldo.

Comment: I have tested it, it works on mac, linix and an online compiler. The casting of the malloc functions isn't necessary. Strictly speaking malloc returns a void*, however it is unnecessary, as this void * is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type. Thereby it makes your code less readable and more error prone. It hides the error for example if you forgot stdlib and can crash

Comment: I tested it in Visual studio and find that you maybe wrong at free m matrix. When you call "   matrix t = newMatrix(*col, *row);" then value of row of t is set prior col of m; and the current value of row is 3.(as the your example).So you call freeMatrix(*m,*row, *col); which mean you will free matrix m with row equals 3 and row equal 2,it is wrong.So you must call    matrix t = newMatrix(*col, *row); Do you think like me?